# Programming judge with versus system

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for a programming judge system which supports putting contestants programs against each other in "matches". The format could be either for example a tournament style or chess ranking, but this isn't that important. A good example would be Google's AI challenge (http://aichallenge.org/)

The only systems I've found so far are "regular" programming judges, i.e. those who can check if a program passes or fails a given problem, like DOMJudge.

Do you know of any systems like this?

Comment: Isn't the source available for aichallenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [Caia](http://www.codecup.nl/download_caia.php). It is used by the Dutch informatics olympiad to organize programming competitions where the submitted programs compete against each other.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I was heavily into linux I remember a battlebot program or something like that where you built a program that would enter the arena with another users program...the victory was determined by wiping out the other program. I can't remember the name of it, but there are systems like that.

**Edit**
I found a [resource](http://www.sumost.ca/steve/games/) that collects similar games and applications that do just this

Comment: Now that's going to bother me because I can't remember the name :|

Comment: Sounds like you might be thinking of [Core War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War).

Comment: @Caleb That's the one!